# Is QA's job only to perform Quality Assurance of developer's work?

Tags: software-development

I am a software developer. I almost always receive unclear and ambiguous requirements from my BA. For almost every new release, BA provides me with a document, and my development is tested on the basis of that document. Now this document contains many types of ambiguities and missing parameters, e.t.c. So first I point out these ambiguities to the BA, which are like around 20-30 per each release. Then I get them approved by BA on email, for which I have to take several follow-ups. And after doing all that, I do the actual development. Now the QA is invisible during all this process. When I complete the development, QA's work actually begins there. He takes out the document, and starts pointing out any ambiguities/misunderstandings from it. Then he approaches me after which I show him the approval on email. On this, the QA says why did you not make him (BA) enter the changes in the document? I mean, it takes a lot of effort and time for me to get clarifications on the document from the BA - that's just the nature of my team. And to be honest, I am just a junior dev, and I can't force 15+ years exp BA to bring changes into the document - I am doing the best I can and the best I can do in this situation is to get the baselined requirements on email. So, the QA then goes around the office telling different people including my leads that I and BA are shipping things by our will, without any approval, e.t.c.

Isn't it the QA's job to actually perform the QA of the requirements? I am actually doing part of his job, and I am getting the heat where I fall short in it. After such defaming, I get to hear comments about me in performance reviews and in casual meetings that I have communication problems, e.t.c. Why is the QA sleeping during the whole process and wakes up 1 to 2 days before deployment? I think the QA should be brave enough to face architects and BAs and clash with them himself regarding their issues instead of boiling every issue down to the developer. Isn't that the QA's role, to perform Quality Assurance of every step of SDLC? What should I do about this situation? (Edited)

Comment: Who is responsible for entering the changes into the document?

Comment: I think this question is best suited for the manager, team lead, or other authority in your company. Who does what is really a matter of policy at your employer.

Comment: @sf02 BA (Business Analyst)

Comment: @Anonymous Then you shouldn't be doing work that the BA has not entered into the document

Comment: There is already a good answer.  But I want to add, a BA tells a developer what to work on, but the developer gets to be critical of all the small details the BA missed.  So your well within your role as a junior developer to ask the BA questions, and have them fix their specs when they are wrong, or even refuse to work on something that is not well drafted without approval for your time from your own manager or team lead.  Your lead can help you decide if a spec is too far gone to be worked on without fixing.  You should seek their guidance.

Comment: What does the written SDLC process document state? If there is not one, that is problem number one that needs addressed.

Comment: If you have the need to get more precise about the question or answers here, there's a dedicated site here for [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8):

> Isn't that the QA's role, to perform Quality Assurance of every step
>   of SDLC?

You seem to feel that there is one SDLC that applies across all companies. That's simply not the case.

Every company I have ever worked for had their own unique SDLC. Some had an SDLC where QA was involved in every step of the process from initial requirements, to release into Production, to post-production checking. Others had an SDLC that didn't get QA involved until the Beta stage. Some SDLCs were waterfall-like. Others were Agile-like. None were exactly the same.

Some companies require strict documentation and document control. If it isn't in the officially-approved documents, it isn't real. Other companies permit hallway conversations, phone calls, and email chains to convey requirements.

> What should I do about this situation?

Your first job should be to understand the actual SDLC currently in effect at your company. Start with your manager and ask for an explanation regarding where you should be finding your input, and what should happen if there is a general consensus for change. Your manager will tell you if you are free to decide for yourself, if you should rely only on the officially-approved documentation, or something else.

I suspect QA has already done the same and has been told to rely solely on the official documentation.

> Is QA's job only to perform Quality Assurance of developer's work?

It might well be. That depends on your company's SDLC. When in doubt, ask your boss.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be working without a spec.  Jr. Programmer or otherwise.  You need to inform the BA that you cannot proceed until the changes you have negotiated are properly reflected in the spec.

You QA engineer is right.  He/she will be validating your work against the published document, not some email chain letter you had with the BA.

Comment: I totally agree with you. QA is doing his job right, but shouldn't he be the one to enforce proper documentation? Why is he asking me to ask something from the BA? When I ask the BA, BA sometimes doesn't take me that seriously. I have my own deadlines and if I withhold my development on basis of some approvals, then I will miss those deadlines.

Comment: On the contrary, if QA doesn't give the sign-off, then it certainly puts the pressure on BA. I mean I'm with the QA on this one, but I believe he (QA) should be the one enforcing the documentation. Am I wrong in this? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your deadline is dependent on getting a valid spec from the BA.  You need to inform the stakeholders that the BA has not given you a valid specification yet and you will be able to start once he/she has given you documented guidance.  If your management is not OK with this, then you need to work with the BA to ensure that changes get applied because QA certainly isn't going to sign off until the spec is right.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on each company, but the going trend these days is no, performing QA at the time development is completed should not be all QA does.  As you've alluded to, QA would ideally be involved in defining what the acceptance criteria is and in so doing would be helping to shape the requirements before you pull up your IDE.

To address it may be difficult because someone's job will change and change--even for the better--is often resisted.  But it doesn't mean you can't help it along.  Depending on your team dynamic you may want to talk with other team members or perhaps go directly to your manager.  Whichever path you take, approach it from a spirit of improvement, not blame or frustration that QA person X keeps throwing a wrench in things.

You may want to suggest a lessons learned session after the release/sprint/unit of stuff completes.  Come to it with some examples of areas where you hadn't realized X and Y that QA later raised.  Ask if it might be possible to borrow some help from QA before you start work to make sure you're working to the same goal they understand.

This is a case where those soft skills we developers aren't terribly known for can help.  How you phrase it can make a big difference between sounding like you’re blaming QA for withholding information vs. thankful for their contribution and that having access to it sooner would be great.  The former predisposes them to not helping, the latter may give you a better chance of buy in.

**EDIT**
If you feel the relationship allows for it, a version of not waiting for a post mortem would be on the next ambiguous design, approach the QA person for assistance.  “Hey [QA person], I’m not clear on some details of this spec [BA person] gave me.  I was going to talk check with her on some clarifications, but was wondering if you might have any insights or perhaps you could join us so we’re on the same page before I start solving for the wrong problem.”

Answer (score 0):

A requirements document should be as clear and unambiguous as possible, and some back-and-forth with the BA is not unusual. The document needs to be updated, however, or else it loses its relevance to the project. So, I'd recommend doing whatever you can on your end to keep that requirements document up to date.

Part of the solution might be involving the QA earlier in the process. Discuss any potential issues with the spec during your daily meeting; or if you don't meet daily, make sure you cc the QA when emailing the BA. Frame the issue as a problem to the team, that the team can work on together.

Remember that, specific roles aside, you all share the common goal of producing quality software. Sometimes coming at an issue with that mindset can help shape a situation.

Answer (score 0):

> He takes out the document, and starts pointing out any ambiguities/misunderstandings from it. Then he approaches me after which I show him the approval on email. On this, the QA says why did you not make him (BA) enter the changes in the document?

At least on this specific point, your QA folks are exactly right.  If you change the understanding of the requirement that is going to be implemented, then that change must be *documented* and the changed version shared with everyone who will ultimately have to compare the work to the requirement.

- If the change is negotiated with an external client (or even internal users), then you need that change to be recorded in the terms of what delivery will be measured against
- If the change is more of an internal *interpretation* of the requirement, then you need to record the interpretation you've decided to work from
- If anyone internal or external in the future may *argue* with the change, you want to record the basis of the decision and factors considered, so those can be reviewed during the dispute - the last thing you want to have to do is go re-research since-forgotten motivations for a change while someone is angry about the fact that it was made.

It sounds like what you should be doing is putting the requirement document into some sort of shared document system where you can mark it up with changes and interpretive notes and share that across the development and QA teams and business stakeholders.

That won't make disputes impossible, but it will divide them into:

- situations where the dispute is over the appropriateness of a requirement change which has been recorded - but you have documented the change along with who approved it and why, so the argument will be with that and not the implementation
- places where the implementation does not match even the revised requirement specification, which is not only a development failure, but one of the primary ones a QA process is intended to catch
- newly noticed problems in the requirement specification, which you can be glad were noticed before the product got out the door
- places where a change was agreed but not reported - a *communication failure* which should be rare, but is currently the cause of most of your frustrations, because your change agreements are not being communicated.

Even if you can't create an *official* revised document, you can still pro-actively go sit down with QA before the testing begins and talk through the requirements document, explaining the agreed upon changes and showing them the emails *before* they have to re-find all of these things as deviations from the spec they have been given.  Hopefully they'll then join you in advocating for keeping official records of specification revisions.

Answer (score -1):

I would set up a meeting between you, the BA, and the QA to determine what procedure to follow when requirements need to be updated.  Find out exactly what is required from you for each of them to be able to do their jobs. Take careful notes and afterward, send out a summary email to document what was said and ask if anything is missing or incorrect.  If they later accuse you of having communication problems, you can refer back to that email to demonstrate you followed the procedure that was agreed upon. It might also be a good idea to ask the more senior devs on your team how they deal with these issues.